# UnitTest formType Symfony 3

Tags: php, forms, symfony, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm trying to get starting the UnitTest process with symfony 3 and I'm still confused how to do that and how to test my forms, I've followed the official documentation and the instructions to create the TestClass :

TestFormType :

```
<?php

namespace Tests\EvalBundle\Form\Type;

use EvalBundle\Form\DepartmentType;
use EvalBundle\Entity\Department;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Test\TypeTestCase;

class DepartmentTypeTest extends TypeTestCase
{
    public function testSubmitValidData(){

        $formData = array(
            'name' => 'test',
        );

        $departmentType = new DepartmentType();
        $form = $this->factory->create($departmentType);

        $department = new Department();
        $department = fromArray($formData);

        $form->submit($formData);

        $this->assertTrue($form->isSynchronized());
        $this->assertEquals($department, $form->getData());
        $view = $form->createView();
        $children = $view->children;

        foreach (array_keys($formData) as $key) {
            $this->assertArrayHasKey($key, $children);
        }


    }


}
?>
```

I've got some `errors` that those functions :

```
fromArray,assertTrue,assertEquals,assertArrayHasKey : they are not undefined.
```

Is some one here familiar with this can help me to understand the concept?

Comment: `fromArray` method don't exist. Also, in my opinion the tests of forms give too much errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- try to use `$this->factory->create(DepartmentType::class)` instead

`$departmentType = new DepartmentType();
$form = $this->factory->create($departmentType);`

If problem still appears it could be cause by one of the following issue:

- Method `fromArray` is not exists in your code. I suggest to feed `Department` object by setters like `$department->setName('test');`. In Symfony3 documentation method `fromArray` was mentioned but we should implement this method by ourselfs
- `assertTrue`, `assertEquals` ,`assertArrayHasKey` - suggested that you are using incorrect `TestTypeCase` class.

**Below I pasted working unit test for form with fields `email` and `surname`**

```
<?php

namespace Tests\AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Test\TypeTestCase;
use AppBundle\Form\RecipientType;
use AppBundle\Entity\Recipient;

class RecipientTypeTest extends TypeTestCase
{
    public function testAddRecipient()
    {
        $formData = array(
            'email' => 'test@gmail.com',
            'surname' => 'Doe',
        );

        $form = $this->factory->create(RecipientType::class);

        $object = new Recipient();
        $object->setEmail($formData['email']);
        $object->setSurname($formData['surname']);

        // submit the data to the form directly
        $form->submit($formData);

        $this->assertTrue($form->isSynchronized());
        $this->assertEquals($object, $form->getData());

        $view = $form->createView();
        $children = $view->children;

        foreach (array_keys($formData) as $key) {
            $this->assertArrayHasKey($key, $children);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider to test forms by functional testing not unit.

Comment: your answer not help

Comment: have you tried that before so you can help me and any other one looking for answer ?

Comment: A good way to learn Symfony test is download same small Bundle form GitHub and analyze code (bundle with info of test cover).    

example test view exit and have HTML tag H1:    

<?php
namespace MyBundle\Tests\Controller;

use MyBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class TasksControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testAllTasks()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();

        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/tasks');
        $this->assertGreaterThan(0, $crawler->filter('h1')->count());
    }
}